# Build Failed in react-native

Tags: android, react-native

I have successfully created and build the app using the react-native framework, but not able to install directly using the cmd as react-native run-android as its showing the path error.

my path is app\build\outputs\apk\debug\apk-debug.apk,

but its showing as app\build\outputs\apk\apk-debug.apk.

So while installation its showing, not able to install due to no such file or directory

Also showing the error type:3

It may be duplicate question for you, but i have tried all the ways but all in vain. If possible help, before marking it as duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally I got the answer.

This type of error comes in react-native while you are installing the apk by the cmd to mobile by command react-native run-android --deviceID "xxxxxxx"

Instead of run directly as react-native run-android.

You might get error as "unknown API level", then its mean you have to update the android studio build tools based on the required platform. I suggest to install all the build tools above 24, as it supports all the android mobile.